# DRYing up event handlers

Tags: jquery, event-handling, dry

I have a modal with three buttons: close, remove and save. Each button requires a click handler, and each click handler hides the modal as its last action. This is the naive approach:

```
// Close
$('#edit-user-close').on('click', function () {
  $modal.modal('hide');
});

// Remove
$('#edit-user-remove').on('click', function () {
  removeUser();

  $modal.modal('hide');
});

// Save
$('#edit-user-save').on('click', function () {
  saveChanges();

  $modal.modal('hide');
});
```

This code feels very much like it could be DRYed up. What techniques/syntax could I use to DRY up those event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code itself seems fine to me. If you wanted to do it under one click handler you could use a class with a `data` attribute to determine the action, try this:

```
<a href="#" class="modal-action" data-action="close">Close/a>
<a href="#" class="modal-action" data-action="remove">Remove user</a>
<a href="#" class="modal-action" data-action="save">Save</a>
```

```js
$('.modal-action').click(function() {
    switch ($(this).data('action')) {
       case 'remove':
           removeUser();
           break;
       case 'save':
           saveChanges();
           break;
    }

    $modal.modal('hide');
});
```

If you're only ever going to have 2 buttons (besides `close`) then the `switch` could be shortened to an `if` statement. I used a `switch` as it's more extensible, should you need to add different button actions in future.